# pandas groupby sum and agg

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    time    amount  user 
0   2020-06     1   A
1   2020-06     1   B
2   2020-04     1   C
3   2020-04     2   A
4   2020-02     1   C
```

I want to make something like that:

```
    2020-02 2020-04 2020-06
A   0       2       1
B   0       0       1
C   1       1       0
```

I am using this code

```
df.groupby(['user','time'])['amount'].sum()
df.unstack().fillna(0).reset_index()
```

but I am getting wrong results.
Is my code correct?

Comment: `df.pivot(index='user',columns='time',values='amount').fillna(0)`? Or `df.pivot_table` with `aggfunc='sum'` if you have values to aggregate.

Comment: Change this in your code `df.groupby(['user','time'])['amount'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
df.set_index(['user','time'])['amount'].unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
time  2020-02  2020-04  2020-06
user                           
A           0        2        1
B           0        0        1
C           1        1        0
```